# Our Big Test is Tomorrow!

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge

My two friends and I are going stir crazy, trying to figure out what we should do today. Maybe you can help! We've narrowed it down to a few choices.

We could:

1. Visit the mouth of a river on an Asian subcontinent.
2. Shout into a microphone and listen for reverberations.
3. Watch a performance written by "The Bard" and verbally applaud.
4. Catch up on our ballroom dance lessons.
5. Take a trip with my dad to a South American city.
6. Put on some dress blues and see if any southerners call us names (we're from New York).
7. Hang out in French Canada and sip some Canadian Club.
8. Leave our penthouse suite and play nine holes.

> What is my first name and the names of my two friends?

Comment: You are Chowzen and your two friends are puzzling.se and english language learners.se

Comment: On the first line: visit The mouth Of a River on An asian Subcontinent which the capital letters are TORAS, a name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of these lines

> clue two letters of the NATO phonetic alphabet.

Visit the mouth of a river on an Asian subcontinent.

> a DELTA in INDIA

Shout into a microphone and listen for reverberations.

> shout into a MIKE, listen for ECHOs

Watch a performance written by "The Bard" and verbally applaud.

> watch ROMEO and JULIET, say BRAVO

Catch up on our ballroom dance lessons.

> do a TANGO or FOXTROT

Take a trip with my dad to a South American city.

> go to LIMA with your PAPA

Put on some dress blues and see if any southerners call us names (we're from New York).

> get called a YANKEE while in UNIFORM

Hang out in French Canada and sip some Canadian Club.

> stay in QUEBEC and drink WHISKEY

Leave our penthouse suite and play nine holes.

> leave your HOTEL to play GOLF

The remaining options are

> Alfa, **Charlie**, Kilo, November, **Oscar**, Sierra, **Victor**, X-ray, Zulu. Your names are likely the three in bold.

Comment: "Sierra" is also a common first name.